# how do I send a image as binary data to my API using angular?

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, post, httprequest

I am trying to make a angular request based on a curl request, this one:

```
 curl -k -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data-binary '@/home/linux-user/Desktop/folder/cool-folder/src/assets/img/default-image.png' -X POST https://$ENDPOINT:6060/v1/user/photo\?id\=3591\&image\=996ab426-eb57-4f79-94f4-cfea9aef2cd9 |  gunzip | jq
```

*FYI: The request is successful but the image arrives corrupted, also I am sending the image to AWS through an api

**ImageService:**

```
  private postHeaders(token: string): HttpHeaders {
      return new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      });
    }

uploadImage(file: File, token: string): Observable<any> {
      const headers = this.postHeaders(token);
  
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
  
      return this.http.post(this.endpoint, formData, { headers, responseType: 'text' })
        .pipe(
          map((response: any) => JSON.parse(response)),
          catchError((error: any) => throwError(error))
        );
    }
```

**Component**

```
onFileChange(event: any) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file)
    if (file) {
      this.imageService.uploadImage(file, this.token)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log(response); // Handle the response data here using 'jq' or other methods.
        }, (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  }
```

[console.log(file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjSyT.png)

**Another example of the component above**

```
tried binary

 onFileChange(event: any) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file)
    if (file) {
      this.readFileContent(file);
    }
  }

  readFileContent(file: File) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const binaryData = e.target.result; // This contains the binary data of the file

      this.imageService.uploadImage(new Blob([binaryData]), this.token)
        .subscribe((response) => {
          console.log(response); // Handle the response data here
        }, (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    };

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  }
```

**Html**

```
<input type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
```

Comment: maybe put directly the file instead of a formdata?

Comment: that was it, post a comment @Grogu

Comment: I was working on it, I'm a bit slow. I had the reverse issue on my app few times ago. We were sending with the angular default file thing in frontend and waiting for `application/csv` content in the back, it was working fine. Then switched to `multipart/form-data` in the backend because it allows more possibilities and to uniformize all our endpoints, and it was broken. `FormData` has fixed the issue, it even automatically sets the content type to multipart form data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, simply passing file is supposed to work, according to that: http://www.sibenye.com/2017/02/17/handling-image-upload-in-a-multitiered-web-application-part-1/

`FormData` must better be used to send `multipart/form-data`.

```js
onFileChange(event: any) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file)
    if (file) {
      this.readFileContent(file);
    }
    
    // part to send data
    let url = '/url';
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    headers.set('Upload-Content-Type', file.type)
    // add authorization etc too
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    this.http.post(url, file, options).subscribe()
  }
```